# How to use copyWith on a freezed union class, that implements a specific mixin

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

Lets say I have this class from the documentation :

```dart
abstract class GeographicArea {
  int get population;
  String get name;
}

@freezed
class Example with _$Example {
  const factory Example.person(String name, int age) = Person;

  @Implements<GeographicArea>()
  const factory Example.city(String name, int population) = City;
}
```

and I have an object of type Example ,
how can I check if the example implements Geographicarea and copy it with Interfacespecific properties?

```dart
var example = Example.city();
//How to check if this instance implements GeographicArea and call copyWith with a GeographicArea specific parameter?
example = example.copyWith(population: 20000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check about it with 'is' keyword

```
var example = Example.city();
if(example is GeographicArea){
     *// TODO Type toy logic here* 
}
```